# When using lstrip on a bunch of lines,only the ones starting with 'r' are getting affected and that 'r' is getting removed keeping other same

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file that contained some emails.
All of those start like following:

```
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
From: zqian@umich.edu
From: rjlowe@iupui.edu
From: zqian@umich.edu
From: rjlowe@iupui.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
From: gsilver@umich.edu
From: gsilver@umich.edu
From: zqian@umich.edu
From: gsilver@umich.edu
From: wagnermr@iupui.edu
From: zqian@umich.edu
From: antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
From: gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
From: louis@media.berkeley.edu
From: ray@media.berkeley.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
From: cwen@iupui.edu
```

My problem was to get unique email ids so I attempted-

```
fhand = open("mbox-short.txt")  
emails=[]
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        l=line.lstrip("From:").rstrip()
        emails.append(l) 
unique = []
for email in emails:
    if email not in unique:
        unique.append(email)
        print(email)
print("\nTotal Unique Contacts=",len(unique))
```

Output-

```
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
wagnermr@iupui.edu
antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
ray@media.berkeley.edu
```

Total Unique Contacts= 11

which is the correct answer BUT-

when i used an extra space in lstrip("From: ") beacause the actual email start after "From: ",this is what i got-

```
fhand = open("mbox-short.txt")  
emails=[]
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        l=line.lstrip("From: ").rstrip()
        emails.append(l) 
unique = []
for email in emails:
    if email not in unique:
        unique.append(email)
        print(email)
print("\nTotal Unique Contacts=",len(unique))
```

Output-

```
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
zqian@umich.edu
jlowe@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
gsilver@umich.edu   
wagnermr@iupui.edu
antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
ay@media.berkeley.edu
```

Total Unique Contacts= 11

So we see that emails starting from r are affected as in their first letter disappers from the output while others are not affected at all.
Please help me understand why this is happening.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by looking at the documentation for [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

> str.**lstrip([chars])**
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.

This means the following part of your code:

```
line.lstrip("From: ")
```

removes every occurrence of `F`, `r`, `o`, `m`, `:` and spaces starting from the left until it finds another character. Some examples:

```
>>> "From: rrabc@example.com".lstrip("From: ")
'abc@example.com'
>>> "From: morF@example.com".lstrip("From: ")
'@example.com'
>>> "  mmmrrroooFFF: x@example.com".lstrip("From: ")
'x@example.com'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now! So when I use "From:",it stops at the first space it encounters because " "is not  inside the stripping criteria,but when i try"From: ",the space is removed and then it jumps to next character which in my case was "r" and hence strips it away .

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split()` amd then access the first element. You can  also use a `set` to get all unique emails.

**Ex:**

```
emails = set()
with open("mbox-short.txt") as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        if line.startswith("From:"):
            emails.add(line.strip().split()[1])

print(emails)
print("\nTotal Unique Contacts=",len(emails))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use `re` to get these mails :

```py
import re

with open("mbox-short.txt", 'r') as f:
    emails= list(set(re.findall(r'[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+', f.read())))
```